# Image positioning with two p within div

Tags: html, css

Please see this code pen for a visual of what I mean

http://codepen.io/MarkRBM/pen/KnztJ

I have a 4 column layout.  `.wrapper` is confined to two cols wide.  `.locstitle` is 1 col wide and `.locsexcerpt` is 1 col wide and they are in the position I want them in.  i want `.locsimage` to be to the left of the `.locsexcerpt` directly under `.loctitle` but I cant get it to move from the bottom of `.locslist`.  If I move the mark-up above the `.locsexcerpt` then it just displays to the right of `.locstitle` and above `.locsexcerpt`.  I think I have narrowed down the issue to the code I have linked to and that is shown below.  Thanks in advance.

Html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="locslist">                       
    <p class="locstitle">Galway</p>
    <p class="locsexcerpt">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, quod quas aut quisquam necessitatibus ut aliquid eligendi sunt voluptas fugitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, quod quas aut quisquam necessitatibus ut aliquid eligendi sunt voluptas fugit!</p>
     <img src="/DevTemplate/img/aranislands.jpg"             alt="" class="locsimage">
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper{
  max-width: 25%;
}

.locslist{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #3475b3;
  margin-bottom: 0.8em;
  width: 49%;
}
.locstitle{
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: top;
  width: 50%;
}

.locsexcerpt{
  visibility: visible;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 45%;
}

.locsimage{
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 45%;
}
```

Comment: I assume that the open div tag is just a typo here, not in the actual code?

Comment: Yeah that was atypo fixed now thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the image underneath the title in the HTML, then add `clear:both;` to the CSS

HTML:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="locslist">                       
    <p class="locstitle">Galway</p>
    <img src="/DevTemplate/img/aranislands.jpg"             alt="" class="locsimage">
    <p class="locsexcerpt">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, quod quas aut quisquam necessitatibus ut aliquid eligendi sunt voluptas fugitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, quod quas aut quisquam necessitatibus ut aliquid eligendi sunt voluptas fugit!</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .locsimage{
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 45%;
  clear:both;
}
```

You could also fiddle with the position itself.

Answer (score 2):

Nest the image inside the header paragraph, and delete the float from the image:

```
<p class="locstitle">Galway
  <img src="/DevTemplate/img/aranislands.jpg" alt="" class="locsimage">
</p>
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VBsDp/6/)** (slide the pane to the right)

[image]

Comment: @Irish1 You can vote up and choose best answer these are different

Answer (score 1):

Just float the .locsexcerpt text block right.

See the codepen. I am sure you will want to add some padding to the image, but the positioning is what you were looking for (as I understood it).

http://cdpn.io/kvjsc

```
.locsexcerpt{
  visibility: visible;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 45%;
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: I could have sowrn I tried float right but obviously I didnt as it worked I can't vote you up either but thanks